# Passing utf-8 table to python from org-mode

Tags: python, pandas, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have a bit of a headache trying to pull in a table from org-to-python-to-pandas and then back to org, when the table contains elements that are utf-8 encoded.

In the example below it's the tbl var that is exposed to python.  I believe this is defaulting to Python elements of type string, not unicode.

These are then imported into a pandas dataframe (although this is just an implementation detail, I suspect) as str type.

```
#+NAME: TBL...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

#+BEGIN_SRC python :preamble "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" :results raw :var tbl=TBL :colnames no                                                                                                                                                              
import orgtools as ot                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
df = ot.org2df(tbl)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

return ot.df2org(df)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#+END_SRC
```

Because pandas thinks it's getting ASCII strings as elements, not UTF-8 elements, I find myself having to iterate each element, set to UTF-8, but then encode back to ASCII so as to not break the type-assumptions pandas has already made.  This works, but obviously I loose the non-ASCII characters, and it's ugly.  See below.

My question is - is there a way to pass the :var tbl=TBL to python in a way that the data contained within each table element is properly encoded as python unicode UTF-8 not ASCII strings?

I believe if this was the case then it would avoid errors further down the line when trying to use the tabluate library to convert back to an org-table.  The tabulate library throws without using my re-encoding as ASCII, but I don't believe this is an issue with tabulate, but with the input provided by the :var being typed as string, but actually containing utf-8.

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
from tabulate import tabulate                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
from unicodedata import normalize 

# Required to use Tabulate library on Org Tables with Unicode characters                                                                                                                                                                                   
def removeUnicode(item):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    if isinstance(item, basestring):                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        return normalize('NFKD', item.decode('utf_8')).encode('ascii','ignore')                                                                                                                                                                            
    else: return item                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

# Convert an Org table, stored in a var in a python src block to a Pandas Dataframe                                                                                                                                                                        
def org2df(orgTblVar):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    return pd.DataFrame(orgTblVar[1:],columns=orgTblVar[0]).applymap(removeUnicode)                                                                                                                                                                        

# Convert a Pandas DataFrame to an Org table                                                                                                                                                                                                               
def df2org(df):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    return tabulate(df, list(df), showindex=False, floatfmt=".8f", tablefmt="orgtbl")
```

I'm using Python 2.7 and emacs24.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

It's not a full answer but having discussed this with one of the Tabulate owners, I've shown it is possible to preserve Unicode by following the UTF-8 decode on the dataframe, with a UTF-8 encode on the actual output from Tabulate.  The problem is nothing to do with Tabulate either!

This is better than my original solution of removing the unicode as is preserves the characters correctly.

I still think it would be nice if you could specify character encoding on both inputs and outputs in Org-Babel, but it unless someone else comments, I don't think this is possible.

See here for discussion and debug sessions in from Org/Python that show the internals:

[Discussion of issue on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate/issues/113/onlys-supports-ascii-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Do you state utf-8 as your encoding in your python code? python 2 is using ascii by default. maybe adding

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

as your first line will fix your problem.

Comment: The pre-amble should take care of that: :preamble "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-"

Comment: Also - I think this only controls the encoding of the actual python script itself, and not the contents of the var that is passed in from emacs?

Comment: Yes sorry, you are right. Your problem reminded me of something i stumbled over but there i had hard coded string.